# Laravel pass return url into auth

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have two front-end login forms. A standard one at /login - after login redirected to home.

One on page /create-post. From this page I want to achieve, when the user logs in to redirect him back to the same page /create-post

I've tried to use in RedirectIfAuthenticated:

```
Redirect::back
session('_previous')['url']
redirect()->intended('/')
```

No of these above don't work. I thought first I would use a hidden input name="redirect_url" or something and detect if the request has this param, but I cannot access the request in the handle.

Whats your solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the `redirectPath()` function

```
public function redirectPath()
{
  if (Session::get('url.intended') == 'create-post')
  {
    return url('create-post');
  }

  return url('/');
}
```